# How to get type from generic pointer type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the next code:

```
template<class RandomIt>
static void SelectionSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
    decltype(*first) res[length];
}
```

For example, I call this function like below:

```
int test[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
SelectionSort(std::begin(test), std::end(test));
```

Then `RandomIt` is `int*`, isn't it? And `decltype(*first)` returns `int&` instead of `int` that I need. How can I change it to get `int` type? Is it possible?

Comment: `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)>`

Comment: Note if `length` is not a compile-time constant, then `res[length]` is not Standard C++.

Comment: @aschepler, it's a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C++11 you can use [std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference), like this:

```
typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*first)>::type
```

Or simply (with C++14)

```
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)>
```

Comment: Links to docs -> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference . A potentially cool SO feature would be auto-linking to API docs

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).  It has a type named `value_type` and will give you the underlying type.  For pointer types `T*` that means you get `T`.  So in your case you can use

```
template<class RandomIt>
static void SelectionSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type res[length];
}
```